# Add individual users to Project in Django

Tags: python, django

I am building a basic project management app using Django, where a Project can have any number of users. How can I create a form to add users one at a time?

The default behavior of Django provides multi-select fields for many to many relationships.

```py
class Project(models.Model):
    project_number = models.IntegerField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    design_manager = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='project_design_manager', null=True, blank=True)
    permit = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, default='')
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    users = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=True, related_name='project_users')
```

I want a dynamic field that allows you to add one user at a time.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a simple form containing a ModelChoiceField.

```
class AddUserForm(forms.Form):
    user = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=User.objects.all())

...

def add_user_to_project(request, project_id):
    project = get_object_or_404(Project, pk=project_id)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = AddUserForm(request POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            project.users.add(form.cleaned_data["user"])
            return redirect("...")
    else:
        form = AddUserForm()
    return render(request, "add_user.html", {"project": project, "form": form})
```

Comment: Thanks! I am not entirely sure on how to integrate this into my existing ProjectForm:
```python
class ProjectForm(forms.ModelForm):
 class Meta:
  model = Project
  fields = ['project_number', 'name', 'permit', 'total_contract_hours', 'users']
```

Comment: Well now this is a completely different question. You asked how to add users one by one to an existing project; how does that relate to this form?

Comment: I apologize I did not phrase my initial question correctly, my actual question is can this be done all in the same form (ProjectForm) or will I need to create separate functionality (new form) for the add user feature?

Comment: But I'm having trouble understanding what "adding users one by one" would mean in the context of an existing form. Do you mean some kind of JavaScript widget?

Comment: That is actually exactly what I was envisioning, once again sorry!